# Radio buttons becomes untappable after isChecked is setted to true in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

Below is my xml:
I have used radiogroup and four radioboxes. Also i have setted their styles to checkbox.

```
  <RadioGroup android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <RadioButton
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chck_box_1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/insColor"
                style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                android:textColor="#154890" android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="383dp"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                android:buttonTint="@color/insColor"
                android:id="@+id/chck_box_2" android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:textColor="@color/chckquesColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                android:id="@+id/chck_box_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/insColor"
               android:textColor="@color/chckquesColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chck_box_4"
                style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                android:buttonTint="@color/insColor"

                android:layout_marginTop="11dp" android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text."
                android:textColor="@color/chckquesColor" android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Below is my kotlin code:

```
   fun chckboxunselect() {
        chck_box_1.isChecked = false
        chck_box_2.isChecked = false
        chck_box_3.isChecked = false
        chck_box_4.isChecked = false
    }
```

I am unchecking the checkbox after a user checked them by using chckboxunselect(). After that the checkbox becomes untappable or uncheckable. I dont understand why is this happening.

Comment: can you post code from which you are calling `chckboxunselect()`

Comment: its already posted

Comment: you posted only chckboxunselect() but from where it is being called?